# Setup bash script for aws ubuntu server node.js installation fails but works when initiated again

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, shell, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run my Express server on aws EC-2 server using bash scripts.
I am calling three other scripts(sleep.sh, server_run and install.sh) from test_server.sh

test_server.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# git clone the repo
# cd to the cloned repo directory
# Run the user’s installation steps which will install any necessary dependencies required for the server to run, with sudo permission
chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
# 1. Run the user’s server execution steps which will bring up the server
# 2. We’ll be running your server_run.sh as a background process (using &) so that we can run the next set of commands
chmod +x server_run.sh
./server_run.sh &
# 3. Add a sleep timer to sleep.sh depending upon how long you want to sleep so that the server is ready.
chmod +x sleep.sh
./sleep.sh
# Execute the GET /memes endpoint using curl to ensure your DB is in a clean slate
# Should return an empty array.
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8081/memes'
# Execute the POST /memes endpoint using curl
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8081/memes' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"name": "xyz",
"url": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612832022002-66ee448468a4?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80",
"caption": "This is a meme"
}'
# Execute the GET /memes endpoint using curl
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8081/memes'
# If you have swagger enabled, make sure it is exposed at localhost:8080
# curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/'
```

server_run.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    cd server/
    # Setup DB or any other environment variables you want to setup.
    npm install
    npm start
```

install.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
    sudo apt update
    wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -
    echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install -y mongodb-org
    sudo systemctl start mongod
    sudo systemctl enable mongod
    # Node
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
    nvm install node
    source ~/.bashrc
    node -v
    npm -v
```

sleep.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Sleep for 60 seconds
sleep 60
```

The problem is when I run test_server.sh for first time it shows

[image]

But when I close this terminal and run test_server.sh from different terminal it works.

Comment: Looks like your PATH environmental variable is not set correctly.

Comment: why it's showing npm command not found?

Comment: The full path of the directory holding the executable may not be in your PATH environmental variable.

Comment: Try adding `source ~/.bashrc` inside your `server_run.sh` and see

Comment: This also not working

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question.  We can't see the text in the image.  Just cut-paste it in the question.  Don't use images.